# listview vb6 from sql: object required

Tags: mysql, listview, vb6

I am learning vb6 from youtube in a short time. but none of the videos that I watch defined well on object required to defined. it get error on line `ListView1.ListItems.Clear` I need to know the details on defined object in vb6, these are my codes.

```
Sub filllistview()
 strsql = "select * from pemilikkenderaan "
 Set rs = cn.Execute(strsql)
 ListView1.ListItems.Clear
 Do While Not rs.EOF
 Set Item = ListView1.ListItems.Add(, , rs!carid)
 Item.SubItems(1) = rs!username & ""
 Item.SubItems(2) = rs!cartype & ""
 Item.SubItems(3) = rs!carcolour & ""
 Item.SubItems(4) = rs!rfidno & ""
 rs.MoveNext
 Loop
 Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this code in a form? Does the form have a control named ListView1 added to it?

Comment: ya from a form and it doesn't. and i just found out the solution this morning. I made several forms where it show and hide after clicking a button, while im following a tutorial that using only one form. So I've made a mistake where the code i wrote is in a wrong form, and it cause the form searching where is the list view that i've been mentioned. Btw, thank you so much for your respond.

Comment: Glad you found out the problem!  Good luck & have fun with the tutorials :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Add Components

2)Add References

check the link below for more:
[list in vb6](http://www.esjay.org/2019/12/23/creating-list-in-vb6-from-sql/)

Try this code:-

```
Private Sub filllistview()
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
cn.ConnectionString = ""
cn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
cn.Open

Dim strsql As String
strsql = "select * from pemilikkenderaan"
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open strsql, cn
ListView1.ListItems.Clear
Dim Item As Nodes

Do While Not rs.EOF
    Set Item = ListView1.ListItems.Add(, , rs!carid)
    Item.Add rs!carid, rs!username, rs!username
    Item.Add rs!carid, rs!cartype, rs!cartype
 Item.Add rs!carid, rs!carcolour, rs!carcolour
    Item.Add rs!carid, rs!rfidno, rs!rfidno
 rs.MoveNext
Loop
Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub cmdCreateList_Click()
filllistview
End Sub
```

Comment: It is good that it solves your problem @AngelaHeely  .If you want more information, visit the page: http://esjay.org